# Spring Security - Custom UserDetailsService and UserDetails stop working Concurrency control

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

So guys,

I have this block in my spring-security.xml who control concurrency session to my system:

```
<security:session-management>
    <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1"/>
</security:session-management>
```

That's ok and working until now.

I made my custom implementation os UserDetailsService and UserDetails to store extra columns in my principal.

Everything works normal, but after this, the concurrency control stop working. The users still loggin multiple times with the same username at same time.

I think that in my custom services I need to implement some other strategy to work with concurrency, but I don't know how.

My custom UserDetailsService is:

```
public class AuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        User user = userService.getByUsername(username);
        CustomUserDetail customUserDetail = new CustomUserDetail(user);
        return customUserDetail ;
    }

}
```

And my custom UserDetails is a simple bean:

```
public class CustomUserDetail implements UserDetails {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean accountnonexpired;
    private boolean accountnonlocked;
    private boolean credentialsnonexpired;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String user_id;
    private String org_id;
    private String email;
    private final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

public CustomUserDetail(User user) {

    this.username = user.getUsername();
    this.password = user.getPassword();
    this.authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
    this.user_id = user.getId();
    this.org_id = user.getOrganization().getId();
    this.email = user.getEmail();

    if(user.isActive()){
        this.accountnonexpired = true;
        this.accountnonlocked = true;
        this.credentialsnonexpired = true;
        this.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Anybody knows what I still need to do?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not changed anything else, I suspect it is that you have not defined an equals method in your CustomUserDetail object. As it is, it just inherits the default one from Object which compares object instances.  Whenever the same user re-logins a new CustomUserDetail instance is created which will be considered different by the framework.
The original User object checks equality by username. That's the way to go with your new implementation.